# Rendering an existing site invite only in Django

Tags: django

For a project I'm working on, we're still undecided whether the site will launch on an invite-only basis, or be open to the general public immediately. Notwithstanding the management of invites, how would one go about to render a public site invite-only in Django?

One way I can come up with is adding @login_required to all views, but that seems to be too labour intensive... In other words, is there a way to restrict the use of the site to those who have login credentials in one swoop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the `privatebeta` application ([PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/privatebeta), [GitHub](http://github.com/pragmaticbadger/django-privatebeta))? It seems like that does what you are looking for. Otherwise you can at least have a look at their middleware component to base your code on.

Comment: There's an interesting link - I should remember to check github more often... Anyway, I see they're restricting access through middleware, which is of course the perfect way to do this. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use signals to catch people that are not logged in:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_started

Or you could fiddle with the urlpatterns somehow, so that the urlpatterns list only contains the required login stuff when you're not logged in. That would work, right?